# Redis Elasticache doesn't work on my Django EBS when setting the DEBUG=False

Tags: python, django, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

Do anyone have any idea why my Redis Elasticache doesn't work on my Django EBS when setting the DEBUG=False but works when setting the DEBUG=True?

Here is my settings.py

```py
import os

from import_export.formats.base_formats import XLSX

EXPORT_FORMATS = [XLSX]

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY= os.environ.get(
    'DJANGO_SECRET_KEY',
)

if 'DJANGO_DEBUG' in os.environ:

    if os.environ['DJANGO_DEBUG'] == 'False' or os.environ['DJANGO_DEBUG'] == '0':

        DEBUG = False

    else:

        DEBUG = True

if 'CacheURL' in os.environ:

    CACHES = {

        "default": {

            "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",

            "LOCATION": [

                os.environ['CacheURL'],

                os.environ['ReplicaCacheURL002'],

                os.environ['ReplicaCacheURL003'],

            ],

            "OPTIONS": {

                "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",

                "ssl_cert_reqs": None,

            },

            "KEY_PREFIX": "example",

            "KEY_FUNCTION": "django_tenants.cache.make_key",

            "REVERSE_KEY_FUNCTION": "django_tenants.cache.reverse_key",

        },

        "select2": {

            "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",

            "LOCATION": [

                os.environ['CacheURL'],

                os.environ['ReplicaCacheURL002'],

                os.environ['ReplicaCacheURL003'],

            ],

            "OPTIONS": {

                "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",

                "ssl_cert_reqs": None,

            }

        }

    }

    CACHE_TTL = 60 * 15

    SELECT2_CACHE_BACKEND = "select2"
```

When I set the DEBUG to False, the redis caching do not work.